# What are some steps to create a mobile web version of website?

Tags: asp.net, mobile-website, data-migration, cloud-hosting

I have built a website with asp.net jquery sql server 2008.Now i want to build a mobile version of it(web,accessible via the browser).Do i have to to migrate data to the cloud?if i build in .NET mobile ,will it be accessible from iphone and adroid as it will be accessible via browser?my website is social directory for places,is there a gps api that can help me to indicate that a user is near a place?

Comment: Probably would have been a good idea to think about the mobile version at the beginning.... That said, Android and iPhone browsers work for most websites anyway, sometimes just offering a different style sheet to adjust the layout can make a big difference.

Comment: I'd bet most of your questions are answered in these posts [Highest Voted 'mobile asp.net' Questions - Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile+asp.net?sort=votes&pagesize=15)

Comment: Thank you guys.how about data?how they can be accessible from a mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a mobile version of a current app that has existing data sources etc theoretically the only thing you should have to change is your front end to be suitable for a mobile browser.

In the end you web server will still be serving the pages as if it was any other normal browser (except it would just be the mobile version), and have the same access to resources (eg. databases0 that the standard site does.

In terms of "the cloud" there is no reason that you need to really host anything in there (web/data server) but if you site ends up getting large and/or you don't want to worry about managing infrastructure issues etc investing in the cloud may be a good idea, there is plenty of reasons to go to the cloud but for what you are trying to achieve it is not a necessity.